# Inserting an array with HSTORE using PHP's PDO

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, hstore

So I'm trying to run a query that inserts some values into my postgres database but I'm running into a few problems. For starters when I run this:

`INSERT INTO DataBin (createdUserId, objectId, objData)
VALUES
('52dcd7c7-d300-4394-9f76-e756237951ce', 'd44279a8-3613-4a3c-9a2a-d74770f58a6e', hstore(ARRAY['f9868417-6e91-4c1b-ab67-bcc9290de085', NOW()::TEXT, '7d1d3e16-8b39-4e80-a068-8ed533377dca', 52.03::TEXT, '2123d903-0030-4cb2-abad-d3a48328be97', 20::TEXT]))
;`

The query seems to work perfectly fine, but when trying to do the following, it gives me an error:

`Notice: Array to string conversion`

```
$db = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=test;user=postgres;password=postgres");

//-- Long ass insert for a databin
      $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO DataBin (createdUserId, objectId, objData) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
      $date = new DateTime();
      $hstore = array($time["id"], $date->getTimestamp(), $weight["id"],'52.03', $height["id"],'20');
      $stmt->bindParam(1, $user["id"]);
      $stmt->bindParam(2, $object["id"]);
      $stmt->bindParam(3, $hstore);
      $stmt->execute();
```

I'm assuming I'm not parsing the array in correctly for the postgres HSTORE to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

hstore is not a standard part of PostgreSQL so I would expect a secondary module would be needed to convert an associative array to an hstore text representation.  hstore is not a complex format.  Basically

```
 "key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2" ....
```

You are going to have to loop through the array and generate an hstore string.